# Linksys WRT54GL - Did we get a lemon?

Tags: networking, linksys, router

I've been having problems with a Linksys WRT54GL router, with latest Linksys firmware.  I've read a LOT of great reviews on this model but we are having instability problems with the network.  Should I RMA this router and get it replaced?  Anyone else with this type of problem?

Comment: Do you have any problems with the wired ports?  What have you done to rule out interference as the source of your problems?

Comment: Yes, there are problems even when using the wired ports.  Given that, we haven't done much to rule out interference.

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend dumping the Linksys firmware and load up DD-WRT. It's a far superior firmware for the WRT54GL with enterprise-like features. Turns that $60 router into a $600 one (software-wise). If it's still having issues, it may be the hardware.

Comment: I've loaded DD-WRT on other WRT54GL routers, but not this one.  I should give it a go and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: +1 for DD-WRT.  It's rock solid.  I just skip straight to DD-WRT on any capable router I configure and save myself the future headache.

Answer (score 1):

We have many WRT54GLs running and we have had our share of lemons; sometimes occurring right out of the box and sometimes after a period of use.  The problems seem to be consistent though:  no internet access for wired clients and no DHCP for wireless.  Also, no remote access.  Usually the power LED on front of the router is rapidly flashing.  Sometimes a restart will temporarily resolve the issue, sometimes not.  Lately I have started just replacing with new ones.

For us, these issues occur regardless of whether or not DDWRT is installed.  Usually I try to flash DDWRT before deploying the router, but sometimes I just dont have time.  We have the same problem with both firmwares.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had to buy a Linksys in a couple of years, but for the few years before that, about 1/3 of the ones we bought were lemons and conked out in just a few months.  Other ones would keep going (and are still going strong).

Comment: Was this before or after Linksys was acquired by Cisco?

Comment: I did once get one that had bad capacitors. I ended up buying new ones and resoldering them myself. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

afaik, most people buy GL only to 'upgrade' it with linux firmware.
try tomato or ddwrt 
put few iptables on it 
and (all) your problem be gone...